# Copy custom woocommerce fields into default fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wrote a woocommerce plugin that creates the following custom checkout fields:

```
billing_street_name
billing_house_number
billing_house_number_suffix

shipping_street_name
shipping_house_number
shipping_house_number_suffix
```

I also added this to the admin pages, but since I cannot hook into get_formatted_billing_address & get_formatted_shipping_address (which are both used to display the addresses in writepanel-order_data.php and shop_order.php) I would like to copy them into the default billing_address_1 & shipping_address_1 like this:

billing_address_1 = billing_street_name + billing_house_number + billing_house_number_suffix

I tried to do this with the following (rudimentary) code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_checkout_field_billing_address_1', array( &$this, 'combine_street_number_suffix' ) );

public function combine_street_number_suffix () {
$key = $_POST['billing_street_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['billing_house_number'];

return $key;
}
```

but that doesn't work - I don't think the $_POST variable gets passed at all?

here's how the hook is created in class-wc-checkout.php:

```
// Hook to allow modification of value
$this->posted[ $key ] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_process_checkout_field_' . $key, $this->posted[$key] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed this using the 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta' hook:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', array( &$this, 'combine_street_number_suffix' ) );

public function combine_street_number_suffix ( $order_id ) {
    // check for suffix
    if ( $_POST['billing_house_number_suffix'] ){
        $billing_house_number = $_POST['billing_house_number'] . '-' . $_POST['billing_house_number_suffix'];
    } else {
        $billing_house_number = $_POST['billing_house_number'];
    }

    // concatenate street & house number & copy to 'billing_address_1'
    $billing_address_1 = $_POST['billing_street_name'] . ' ' . $billing_house_number;
    update_post_meta( $order_id,  '_billing_address_1', $billing_address_1 );

    // check if 'ship to billing address' is checked
    if ( $_POST['shiptobilling'] ) {
        // use billing address
        update_post_meta( $order_id,  '_shipping_address_1', $billing_address_1 );
    } else {
        if ( $_POST['shipping_house_number_suffix'] ){
            $shipping_house_number = $_POST['shipping_house_number'] . '-' . $_POST['shipping_house_number_suffix'];
        } else {
            $shipping_house_number = $_POST['shipping_house_number'];
        }

        // concatenate street & house number & copy to 'shipping_address_1'
        $shipping_address_1 = $_POST['shipping_street_name'] . ' ' . $shipping_house_number;
        update_post_meta( $order_id,  '_shipping_address_1', $shipping_address_1 );         
    }


    return;
}
```

I don't think this code is very elegant though (the suffix check part specifically), so if anyone has tips on improving it - very welcome!